# Que la cantidad de materia prima disminuya segun su fecha de vencimiento

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure

Estoy intentando hacer un algoritmo que según la `fecha_vencimiento` de la materia prima me disminuya las `unidades_disponibles` en 1.

Por ejemplo
Si tengo la materia prima  `banano con crema` y sus unidades_disponibles son `1234` y su fecha de vencimiento es `2020-11-04`,  Yo quiero que Como su fecha de vencimiento ya pasó, entonces las unidades disponibles  de  `banano con crema` disminuyan en uno es decir que ya no sea `1234` si no que sea `1233`.

La idea es que la materia prima disminuya segun su fecha de vencimiento.¿Cuando?, Siempre el algoritmo se deberia ejecutar siempre de manera individual en cada registro.

Lo he intentado por medio de un procedimiento almacenado

```
    DELIMITER $$
    create procedure sp_MateriaCaducada()
    begin

update tblmateriaprima set unidades_disponibles = unidades_disponibles-1 where fecha_vencimiento > now;
end
```

A continuación , la estructura de mi carpeta de archivos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No tengo muy claro **donde poner el algoritmo** así que pensé en aplicarlo a el archivo inventario_materia.php , que es **el index donde se muestran todos los registros de la tabla tblmateriaprima** :

```
<?php 
{ 
    session_start();
    error_reporting(0);
 
    if(empty($_SESSION['rol']))
    {
        header('location: ../ingreso/login.php');
    }
 
}
CODIGO DEL PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO

//llamar procedimiento 
$proc= $conexion->prepare(" CALL  sp_MateriaCaducada()");
//ejecutar procedimiento
$m = $proc->execute();

echo $m;


?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Entradas | Materia prima</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script> <!---libreria jquery--->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <link  rel="icon" href="../img/logo_prov_pestaña.png"  >
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/estilos/materia_prima.css">
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../bootstrap/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>            
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fa9adf4dd2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    </head>
        <header class="d-flex justify-content-between">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-start  mb-3 ">
               <?php include "../includes/btnVolver.php"; ?>
            </div>
                <center>
            <h3 class="titulo display-4 ">INVENTARIO DE MATERIA PRIMA </h3>
              </center>  
              <form action="buscar.php" method="post" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ">
                   <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Buscar" name="busqueda" id="busqueda"  aria-label="Search" ata-placement="bottom" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Busque por el código o el nombre de la materia prima">
                  <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn-search form-control mr-sm-2" >
                </form>
        </header>
       
    <body>  
            <br><br><br>
          <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
             <thead class="thead-light">

                <th>Código</th>
                <th>Nombre</th>               
                <th>Cantidad</th>            
                <th>Unidad de medida</th>
                <th>Fecha de vencimiento</th>
                <th>Actualizar</th>
                <th>Eliminar</th>
               
            <?php 
                     
                    include "../includes/conexion.php";
                    $seleccionar = $conexion->query("SELECT mp.codigo as'codigo',mp.nombre as 'nombre',
                    mp.unidades_disponibles as 'cantidad',mp.fecha_vencimiento,
                    um.nombre as 'unidad_medida' 
                     FROM tblmateriaprima as mp INNER JOIN tblunidadmedida as um 
                     ON mp.unidad_medida=um.codigo 
                      ");
                        while ($datos = $seleccionar -> fetch_assoc()) 
                        {
            ?>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                            <td data-label="Código"><?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?></td>
                            <td data-label="Nombre"><?php echo $datos['nombre'] ?></td>
                            <td data-label="Cantidad"><?php echo $datos['cantidad'] ?></td>
                            <td data-label="Unidad Medida"><?php echo $datos['unidad_medida'] ?></td>
                            <td data-label="Fecha de Vecimiento"><?php echo $datos['fecha_vencimiento'] ?></td>
                            <td><a href="actualizar_materia.php?codigo=<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>">ACTUALIZAR</a></td>
                            <td><a href="borrar_materia.php?codigo=<?php echo $datos['codigo'] ?>">ELIMINAR</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
            <?php }   //se cierra ciclo while ?>          
        </table>
    </div>
    </body> 
</html>

<?php

include ("../includes/desconexion.php");

?>
```

**Al implementar el codigo del procedimiento y querer imprimirlo por medio de la variable `$m` , el archivo inventario_materia.php  no ejecuta nada y sale todo en blanco .**

Comment: Y en que momento quieres que se haga el llamado a la acción? al momento de registrar el producto? al momento de que se registre o se elimine otro registro? Es decir en que momento tienes estipulado que el script se ejecute y como.

Comment: @LuisAlfredoSerranoDíaz  **1** Si La condicion es con los dias. **2** Quiero hacer el llamado del algoritmo cuando la materia prima se registre.

Comment: @gbianchi Es que yo no tengo tampoco claro como hacer el algoritmo,  pero lo que debo lograr es **que según la fecha_vencimiento de la materia prima me disminuya las unidades_disponibles en 1** Como seria con un update trivial, Como dijiste?

Comment: Si ya el registro lo tienes en la base de datos que necesitas que se registre para que el disparador se ejecute?

Comment: update tabla set unidades_disponibles = unidades_disponibles-1 where fecha_vencimiento > now.. eso lo hace para todos los registros que cumplan la condicion.. no se para que necesitas algo mas... igual, si esto es produccion, no suena a que este nada bien....

Comment: esto es un sistema real? entonces debe haber reglas para los vencimientos.. no vence un solo producto, seguramente vence un lote completo... igual, el query es como te pase... no necesitas mucho mas.. salvo que tengas que loguear o hacer otras cosas...

Comment: pasate por el [chat] y lo hablamos si queres

Comment: solamente debes entrar.. es el chat del sitio...

Comment: @gbianchi  jaja si pero debo crear un room ? o como se hace, disculpa soy muy nueva en esto , o porque mejor no seguimos aqui ? Que diferencia habria si se debe iniciar sesion para entrar al registro de las materias primas ? Poner el codigo de sesion arriba ?

Comment: no entiendo que tiene que ver iniciar sesion con esta pregunta...te decia lo del chat por todas estas cosas.. ademas alli hay mas gente que puede ayudarte... y los comentarios, no son para discusiones extendidas.. el propio sistema nos manda a un chat...